# How to I tell the type checker a type signature in binding matches the top level type signature?

Tags: haskell, typechecking, parametric-polymorphism

**Background**

I like to add type signatures to my `where` and `let` bindings some times as it helps me remember what I need my results to be and what my inputs are.  It also helps the type checker give me a clear error message when I get it wrong.  However, it has been causing me problems recently:

**Given**

This is an admittedly contrived minimum example:

```
data Foo a = Foo a | NotFoo                  -- 3 
                                             -- 4 
data Bar a = Bar a                           -- 5 
                                             -- 6 
funct :: Bar a -> (a -> Foo a) -> Bar a      -- 7 
funct (Bar x) fn = loop (Bar x, Foo x)       -- 8 
  where                                      -- 9 
    loop :: (Bar a,Foo a) -> Bar a           -- 10
    loop (x, (Foo y)) = loop (Bar y, fn y)   -- 11
    loop (x, NotFoo) = x                     -- 12
```

GHC spits back an error:

```
min_test.hs:11:41: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `a1'
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          loop :: forall a1. (Bar a1, Foo a1) -> Bar a1
        at min_test.hs:10:13
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          funct :: forall a. Bar a -> (a -> Foo a) -> Bar a
        at min_test.hs:7:10
    * In the first argument of `fn', namely `y'
      In the expression: fn y
      In the first argument of `loop', namely `(Bar y, fn y)'
    * Relevant bindings include
        y :: a1 (bound at min_test.hs:11:19)
        x :: Bar a1 (bound at min_test.hs:11:11)
        loop :: (Bar a1, Foo a1) -> Bar a1 (bound at min_test.hs:11:5)
        fn :: a -> Foo a (bound at min_test.hs:8:15)
        funct :: Bar a -> (a -> Foo a) -> Bar a (bound at min_test.hs:8:1)
```

*TL;DR* = GHC cannot infer that the `a` in the type signature on line 7 is the same as the `a` in the type signature on line 11.

If I comment out line 11 everyone is happy.

**Question**

Is there a way to place write a type signature for `loop` in such a way that GHC / Haskell knows that it is the same `a` in both places?

Comment: How about [ScopedTypeVariables](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables)?